# How can I pass values from the imported contacts list of an outbound campaign to the IVR Script?

Tags: voip, cisco, ivr, outbound

I created an outbound campaign on CISCO UCCX 1151, assigned an IVR Script to it, Then I Imported Contacts list in the form of a comma separated text file:

This is the structure of the file :
AccNumber,FirstName,LastName,Phone1

This is example data:
1,Mark,Tomson,0566345

How can I pass the account number to the IVR Script?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the VoiceXML langage check the reference manual. The VoiceXML platform extensions) generally allows to get extra variables from the session context or internal objects. I hope it is the case with CISCO...

Answer (score 0):

After research we found out that its a product limitation, we cannot pass all values from the imported contacts list to the IVR Script , we can only pass the Account Number to the IVR. how ever in an agent based outbound campaign all variables can be passed form the imported contacts list to the finesse desktop interface.

As a workaround, we applied extra DB access with custom java code in order to get the other fields like FirstName, LastName, etc ...